# Can you tell Excel not to recalculate a cell whose contents are based on a COM component?

Tags: excel, com, worksheet-function

I've got an Excel spreadsheet that uses a C# Component.

The component is an Excel Add-in and it's called via a cell's formula function.

ie

```
=MyCalculation(C24)
```

The cell C24 has a hard coded value in it, ie text that never changes and isn't based off of a formula.

However, if I instrument my C# code for the MyCalculation I find that it's called 3 different times for each cell that has that formula during the setup.

I've cached the calculation on the C# side but I'd like to know if there anyway to tell Excel that this value never changes and it only needs to look it up once?

I assumed that if its dependencies never change then it wouldn't recalculate the value.

Comment: Are the 3 calls causing you an issue? In host/add-in scenarios, if you're exposing a general function, you shouldn't have any dependencies on when/how that function is called, unless it's a documented part of the contract (e.g. if it's documented that `Init` will be the first function called, it's fine to code with that assumption in mind)

Comment: > Are the 3 calls causing you an issue?  Just speed of recalculation. I've done what I can to cache results but with so many cells that reference COM calls this is starting to affect performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel's calculation algorithm is such that it frequently calculates formulae/functions more than once. Usually (but version dependent) after the initial calculation has determined a final calculation sequence the formulae/functions only get recalculated when they are dependent on a cell that has been dirtied (note that setting a cell to "Fred" dirties the cell even if it already contains "Fred") or is volatile.
However there are also more unusual circumstances that cause cells to be recalculated.
There is more information about this at my [website](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm).

There is no way of telling Excel never to recalculate a formula, (apart from converting the formula to a constant) except by inhibiting calculation for an entire sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  anythoughts on calcualting the cell data in the onopen event for the worksheet and storing the value in the cell directly at that time?

Comment: Sure you could do that in the open event. Also its not clear what you mean by "during setup", but maybe you should be setting calculation to manual during setup and then switch back to automatic later.

Comment: If your problem is the slow speed of your C# functions check out Excel DNA which will probably make them run faster.